# Could someone help me clarify the steps for this solution?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^6} = \frac{\pi^6}{945},$$
calcuate $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+2)^6}.$$

Solution:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+2)^6} = \frac{1}{3^6} + \frac{1}{4^6} + \frac1{5^6}+\dots\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+2)^6} = \sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{1}{n^6} = \left(\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^6}\right) - \frac{1}{2^6}$$
I don't really understand the second part where my teacher found that the sequence with n at 1 for 1/(n+2)^6 equals to the sequence with n at 3 for 1/n^6. Could someone help clarify why he chose to do this for me? I'm not really sure why he took the steps that he chose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equality is due to the fact that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+2)^6} = \frac{1}{3^6} + \frac{1}{4^6} + \frac1{5^6}+\dots$$
and

$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{1}{n^6} = \frac{1}{3^6} + \frac{1}{4^6} + \frac1{5^6}+\dots$$

The equations have the same right-hand side, so their left-hand sides are equal as well.

Comment: Thank you I understand it now

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^6}=\frac{1}{1^6}+\frac{1}{2^6}+\frac{1}{3^6}+\frac{1}{4^6}+\dots$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+2)^6}=\frac{1}{3^6}+\frac{1}{4^6}+\dots$$
$$=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^6}\right)-\frac{1}{1^6}-\frac{1}{2^6}$$
Do you understand it now?